# unable to connect to Impala(on AWS) from Talend (on prem)

Tags: cloudera

I am trying to connect to Impala which is hosted on AWS from Talend Open Studio for Big Data which is installed on one of the jump host which is on-premise.

When I configure the ImpalaConnection processor and try to run it's giving below error.

> [statistics] connecting to socket on port 3472
>        [statistics] connected
>        [WARN ]: org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Unable to load 
>         native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes 
>         where applicable
>         [ERROR]: org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell - Failed to locate the winutils 
>         binary in the hadoop binary path
>         java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe 
>         in the Hadoop binaries.
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:404)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:419)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.(Shell.java:412)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.(StringUtils.java:79)
>         at 
>         org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:166)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.(Groups.java:130)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.(Groups.java:98)
>         at 
>     org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:432)

Then I tried downloading winutils.exe and submitting in JVM Arguments while running Talend job then it is giving below error.

Error: Could not find or load main class C:\winutils\bin\

Not sure if I am missing anything here. Any help would be appreciated.